# Is it efficient to pass an unordered_map/unordered_set by value in funciton? c++

Tags: c++, set, hashtable, unordered-map, unordered-set

Is it efficient to pass an unordered_set by value ?

i have read that unordered_set constains a large array of buckets, even when there are less elements.
If it contains few elements (N ~ 10), then what will be the time complexity of copying the unordered_set to new unordered_set?
will it be O(N) or something else?

(previously the question was a little ambiguous so I edited to make it more clear.)

Comment: As a rule of thumb I always recommend to pass class objects as pointers or reference. I'm not really experienced with buckets, but even if our `st` has a pointer to them, `unordered_set<int>` could contain additional members which doesn't make sense to copy. Always trying to avoid copy for class objects also helps with code consistency

Comment: When you pass the `unordered_set` by value it is copied, thus all of it's contents are copied, no matter how they are stored. (unless copy elision applies of course). Passing by reference is better in most cases.

Comment: actually the function calculates different subproblems with different calls so passing it by reference will not give accurate results...

Comment: @stark _actually the function calculates different subproblems with different calls so passing it by reference will not give accurate results_ — I don't understand at all this conclusion. Why passing by reference should lead to inaccurate results?

Comment: Your question lacks details. How to pass the parameter depends on what the function does, and you have not given any details on that. Also, to make your question even more confusin you add in *function calculate different subproblems with different function calls, so passing by reference will give inaccurate/unwanted results* without really explaining what you mean. Pointless question as it stands. Add enough details.

Comment: @DanielLangr I have added more details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you always need a copy of `st` to modify, then you may as well do the copying in the call.

If you sometimes need a copy of `st` to modify, it might be better to pass by (const) reference, and make the copy in the body when you need it.

If you never need a copy of `st` to modify, it's generally better to pass by (const) reference.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what does your function do with that container, does it change the container content or only? Should those changes be available after your function done its job?

So, if you want to change the container inside your function but changes shouldn't affect the origin container - then pass your container by value or a const reference and then do a copy of this container inside your function.

It doesn't matter what type of container you use list, vector on unordered_map but the operations done for those data do matter